# Computer Code Friendly Books On Differential Equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematica

When I need a differential equation for this or that application I generally search (by hand) through old paper and ink books written by mechanical or electronical (electrical) engineers. Sometimes my journey takes me back centuries to the works of Richard Anthony Proctor and A. R. Forsyth. Which brings me to my question.

Could somebody point me to a book that acknowledges the work of these masters, and, at the same time, translates their symbology to the language of Mathematica?

I'm noticing Mathematica is getting more and more 'code friendly' with every new version. I'm getting scared.